# Mail Sending But Not On Submit?

Tags: php, email

I am a PHP novice here. I have a send mail script that looks like this:

```
$to      = 'example@email.com';
$from    = 'noreply@email.com';
$subject = 'Test Submission';
$message = 'This is just another test.';
$headers = 'From: example@email.com' . "\r\n" .
// 'Reply-To: example@email.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This script works fine and sends an e-mail when the page is loaded. The problem is that when I alter the script just enough so that the form is not submitted until the Submit button is clicked then all of a sudden nothing works anymore. Here is the altered code I have been trying to use (and which seems to go right along with what the PHP site suggests):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to      = 'example@email.com';
    $from    = 'noreply@email.com';
    $subject = 'Test Submission';
    $message = 'This is just another test.';
    $headers = 'From: example@email.com' . "\r\n" .
    // 'Reply-To: example@email.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML form as well?

Comment: Have you a html markup for your post ?

Comment: This assumes there is a form who's method is POST and has an input in it with a name of `submit`

Comment: Hmm, interestingly enough I am using HTML markup with a form that doesn't have name="submit" in it but had still worked without it in prior projects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your submit button on your form has a NAME attribute. The value of that NAME attribute is what gets sent to the server, so:

`<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Go!">`

...would result in this variable and value:

`$_POST["btnSubmit"] = "Go!";`

...and you would check it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
{
  ...
}
```